# Multiple email recipient using wp_mail()

Tags: wp-mail

I want to define multiple recipients email address outside the array. like

```
$adminmail = get_option(admin_email);
$adminmail2 = like an email address;
$multiple_recipients = array($adminmail,$adminmail2);
$subj = 'The email subject';
$body = 'This is the body of the email';
wp_mail( $multiple_recipients, $subj, $body );
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 17):

Yes it's possible, `$to` accepts an array or comma-separated list of email addresses to send message.

You can read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), about optional headers parameter that can add from, cc, content-type, fields.

If you want to send automaticaly WordPress admin notifications, you can have a look to [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/brozzme-multiple-admin-emails/).